# SLURM srun run a python script not in parallel, but have access to the parallel resources

Tags: python, tensorflow, mpi, slurm

I'm trying to run a python script in which part of the code is going to be parallelized according to some SLURM environment variables. I don't think the exact code is important, but for reference, I would like to [use this](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/distribute/cluster_resolver/SlurmClusterResolver) to train my networks.

Now, the problem is that I need to run my script via `srun`, however this will spawn multiple parallel instances of my script which I don't want.

The most basic example would be this:

```
#!/bin/sh
#SBATCH -N 2
#SBATCH --ntasks=2

srun python myscript.py
```

Now I will have 2 nodes and 2 tasks, meaning that when I run `python myscript.py` there will be 2 instances of `myscript.py` running in parallel.

However, this is not what I want. I would like there to be only one instance of `myscript.py` running, however it should have access to the environment variables set by `srun`, and leave it to the python script to properly distribute the resources.
settings `srun --ntasks=1` does not work, since then the script will only 'see' one of the nodes.

Is it possible to use `srun` to run a single instance of the script while it still has 'access' to the SLURM environment variables? I've looked at options such as `--exclusive` and `--preserve-env`, but they do not seem to help me in this case.

Comment: Judging by the code present in `SlurmClusterResolver`, it is expected that there are multiple copies of the script running in parallel. For example: `self._rank = int(os.environ['SLURM_PROCID'])` or `self._rank = int(os.environ['OMPI_COMM_WORLD_RANK'])`. You don't have Open MPI world rank in the environment unless the process has been launched with `mpiexec`.

Comment: See [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/b083ceafd48b3c8e4d9dfcc40a6b743bed7b371a/tensorflow/python/distribute/cluster_resolver/README_Slurm.md). You are supposed to allocate multiple nodes and then launch multiple copies of the script. The distribution strategy will then take care of doing the right thing in each copy.

Comment: That was my initial expectation as well. However, what actually happens is that each run of the script will try to allocate all 4 resources for itself, and distribute it over them. So I end up with 4 processes that each try to distribute over the 4 so tasks. Obviously this does not work as they try to allocate the same resources for themselves. Perhaps I should have a look at SLURM_PROCID and OMPI_COMM_WORLD_RANK and make sure those are set correctly.

Comment: Maybe you should extract the relevant portions of your script and put them in your question?

Comment: You were right, there should be multiple processes. Something else in my code caused TensorFlow to overly eagerly allocate resources causing the errors. I've given a detailed answer for future purposes below. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out that Hristo Iliev was right in the comments, to use the SlurmClusterResolver properly multiple jobs need to run in parallel. 
This can be a bit confusing as everything will be printed multiple times because everything is run in parallel, but this is normal.

However, my initial confusion and my assumption that it must be done as stated in the original question came from TensorFlow reporting out of memory errors whenever I tried to use the MultiWorkerMirrored strategy, whereas I knew that without this the model fitted perfectly within the available memory.

Somewhere I made a call to `tf.config.get_visible_devices("GPU")` in my code. Now in order for TensorFlow to get the GPUs, it will allocate them, and by default does so by filling up the complete GPU memory. However, since all scripts are running in parallel, each script will try to do this for themselves (since this is done outside the scope of the strategy), resulting in out of memory (OOM) errors.

After removing this piece of code, everything ran fine.

Suggestion for people that might stumble upon this post in the future:
- Scripts are supposed to be run in parallel, you will see multiple times the same outputs
- Make sure that everything is done under `strategy.scope()`, i.e. model compiling, data generation setup (using tf.data)
- Pay special attention to saving the model; only the 'main' worker should save the model to the real save file, the others should write to temporary files [see here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/distribute/multi_worker_with_keras#saverestore_outside_modelcheckpoint_callback)

If you get out of memory errors; make sure that there is not some piece of code that allocates all the GPUs outside of the scope. This can be some initiation somewhere by TensorFlow, but if this is present in all scripts it will cause OOM errors. A handy way to test this is to use `tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth`, to allow memory growth instead of full memory allocation.

In my code, I used the `get_task_info()` function of `tf.distribute.cluster_resolver.SlurmClusterResolver`, and only ran functions that allocate memory when the task number was 0, the main worker.

(Above functions and comments are based on TensorFlow 2.2.0 and Python 3.7.7)